# Counting rows when groupBy by several fields

Tags: mysql, sql

I have follow query

```
Select parent.*,

( Select ?????????
     from  event e
     where  e.company_id = parent.company_id
       AND e.event_type_id in (10, 11, 12)
       AND  
        e.email in 
         (Select DISTINCT u.email
             from  users u  where  u.parent_id = parent.id )


     and e.subject_id in 
        (Select DISTINCT s.subject_id from  subjects s  where s.parent_id = parent.id ) 
    GROUP by e.email, e.subject_id ) as done

from parent_table parent
```

I need put something  instead ???????? to count subquery rows

I tried to wrap it  with another subquery

```
Select count(*)  from (.........)
```

but in this case  my inner query not see parent table

`Unknown column 'parent.company_id' in 'where clause'`

subquery itself returns table like

```
----------------------------------------
|   email   |    subject    |    count  |
----------------------------------------
|   email1  |    1          |    1      |
|   email2  |    5          |    3      |
|   email3  |    20         |    22     |
```

so its events count by  email-subject pairs

on top level I need  just number of such pairs

UPDT:

seems

`COUNT(DISTINCT e.email, e.subject_id)`
instead 
`GROUP by e.email, e.subject_id )`
works fine for me

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  A correlated subquery only works when it returns zero or one rows; yours is returning multiple rows so something is amiss.

Comment: I understand
As I say, I need  same result if i wrap query with  `Select count(*)  from (.........)`
but in this case  I have `Unknown column 'parent.company_id' in 'where clause'` error

if I  hardcode  parent.id and  parent.company  inside  -  it exact what i need

Answer (score 0):

```
( Select COUNT(DISTINCT e.email, e.subject_id)
     from  event e
     where  e.company_id = parent.company_id
       AND e.event_type_id in (10, 11, 12)
       AND  
        e.email in 
         (Select DISTINCT u.email
             from  users u  where  u.parent_id = parent.id )


     and e.subject_id in 
        (Select DISTINCT s.subject_id from  subjects s  where s.parent_id = parent.id )  ) as done

from parent_table parent
```